# How to manipulate URL while executing Test cafe scripts

Tags: javascript, testcafe

I tried executing my TestCafe scripts using command prompt. While executing, test cafe starts execution by taking local IP, port number and session ID along side the URL. I want my scripts to execute directly on the URL without the local host IP, port and other details. Refer attached screenshot when I executed my scripts on Test Cafe.
[Screenshot of test cafe script with local host IP, port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQNwq.png)

Attached is the code for test case which was executed on Test Cafe.

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
import { Crypto } from 'testcafe';
var faker = require('faker');
function randomString(size) {  
    return crt
    .randomBytes(size)
    .toString('hex')
    .slice(0, size)
};

function numberGen(len) {       //Function to Generate random number; 
length of number = value specified in 'len'
 //  var genNum= Math.floor(Math.pow(10, len)*Math.random()).toString()
  var text = "";
    var charset = "0123456789";
    for( var i=0; i < len; i++ ) {
    text += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length));}
    return text;
};
 const dataSet = require('./dataIUT.json');
const crt   = require('crypto')
var randomBankAccName = faker.random.alphaNumeric(6)+"Bank";
var AccountNumber = numberGen(9)
var AccountName = "AccName_"+faker.random.alphaNumeric(4)
fixture `CreateBankAccount`
.page `https://dev-assure-claims.dxc-rmcl.com/riskmasterux/#/login? 
clientId=3f28130450c00018`
.beforeEach(t => t.resizeWindow(1200, 1100));

dataSet.forEach(data => {    
test('CreateBankAccount', async t => {


//==================Login Code With JSON Starts================================       
    await t
    .maximizeWindow()
    .typeText(Selector('#username'), data.Username)
    .pressKey('tab')
    .typeText(Selector('#login-password'), data.Password)
    .pressKey('enter')
    .click(Selector('[ng-model="dsnSelected"]'))
    .click(Selector('[role="option"]').find('span').withText(data.DSN))
    .click(Selector('[ng-model="zoneSelected"]'))
    .click(Selector('[role="option"]').find('a').withText('Claims'))
    .click(Selector('#loginbox').find('button').withText('Continue'))
    .wait(1000)
//==================Login Code With JSON Ends================================    

//==================Code to Create Bank Account Starts ================================    

    .click(Selector('#menuBar').find('a').withText('Funds').nth(0))
    .click(Selector('#menu_FundsRoot').find('a').withText('Bank Account'))

    .switchToIframe(Selector('[id^="bankaccount"]'))
    .wait(1000)
    //var BankAccount = "BA_"+randomString(4).toUpperCase()
    //await t
    .click(Selector('#lookup_banklastname'))
    .typeText(Selector('#lookup_banklastname'), randomBankAccName).setTestSpeed(0.6).pressKey('tab')
    //.click(Selector('#accountnumber'))         
    .typeText(Selector('#accountnumber'), AccountNumber).setTestSpeed(0.6)
    .pressKey('tab')           
    .click(Selector('#accountname')).typeText(Selector('#accountname'), AccountName).setTestSpeed(0.6)
    .pressKey("tab")
    .click(Selector('#Save').find('i').withText('save'))
//==================Code to Create Bank Account Endss==================================

//========================Click to RHS Child's Add button Starts=========================
    const ele1 = Selector('[class="row main_menu right-panel-bg-hover"]').find('i').withText('add').with({ visibilityCheck: true }) // RHS Menu is available
    await t.expect(ele1.exists).ok('', { timeout: 20000 })
    .click(ele1)
//========================Click to RHS Child's Add button Ends=========================

//==========================Logout Code Starts==========================================
    .switchToMainWindow()
    .click(Selector('#morebtn').find('i').withText('more_vert'))
    

.click(Selector('#menu_othersMenu').find('a').withText('exit_to_appLogout'))
     .click(Selector('#btnRoll').find('i').withText('done'));
//===========================Logout Code Ends========================================
```

});});

Comment: Could you supply your test code?

Answer (score 1):

What issues is having the tests "run" on localhost causing you? What exactly are you trying to solve for?

What you're seeing is TestCafe communicating with the [local TestCafe server.](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402662/reference/testcafe-api/global/createtestcafe) Looking at the docs, it isn't possible to have TestCafe communicate with a device that isn't your current machine, so I don't think what you want to achieve is possible.

Comment: I wanted to scan the requests through test cafe scripts on burp tool to achieve security testing

Comment: You can use Testcafe's intercept to log all HTTP requests: https://testcafe.io/documentation/402842/guides/advanced-guides/intercept-http-requests. You could then use the output from that to run them through burp, I believe. I haven't used burp so I'm not entirely sure on that.